# How to Add a graphics card driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution

I am brand new to Ubuntu and Linux, so please forgive my inexperience.

During installation, the OS did not detect my graphics card and all that appears under the display settings is the "Built in display" which will not allow me to change any settings and unhappily is set to a 640 x 480 resolution.

I have a Matrox G200eR2 Graphics card, installed on a Dell Poweredge T130 server, running the Ubuntu Desktop OS.  I have downloaded the correct proprietary driver for Linux from the Matrox website and have extracted it to a folder Named Matrox Driver which is under the downloads file folder.

My question is, where (in what folder) do I place the Graphics card driver so that the Ubuntu Desktop OS recognizes it and allows me to change the resolution?

Comment: There must be an installation manual in the driver archive.

Comment: possible reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1316035

Comment: I followed the steps to install the driver.

Comment: I followed the steps to install the driver.  Only after downloading the driver, and when I ran the sudo ./install.sh command the following happened:  
sudo ./install.sh
 ./install.sh: 39: [: x86_64: unexpected operator
./install.sh: 57: ./install.sh: function: not found
./install.sh: 69: ./install.sh: function: not found
./install.sh: 78: ./install.sh: function: not found
./install.sh: 95: ./install.sh: function: not found

Please enter the full path to your current X11R6 directory: 
Example: /usr/X11R6/

Comment: I entered the following after searching for the X11R6 directory and not finding it: home/craig/Drivers/

Comment: I then received the following:

./install.sh: 141: 
./install.sh: function: not found
./install.sh: 151: test: ./xserver/Revision: unexpected operator
./install.sh: 153: [: Revision 0: unexpected operator
./install.sh: 156: [: Revision 0: unexpected operator
./install.sh: 160: [: Revision 0: unexpected operator
./install.sh: 163: [: Revision 0: unexpected operator
./install.sh: 166: [: Revision 0: unexpected operator
-e \E[31mERROR: The X server drivers included in this installation package -e  do not support the current version of your X server.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue on my R515, same GPU. `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-mga` helped get me to a usable resolution. I enabled SSH, `nomodeselect`, and installed Team Viewer but it's unusably slow. Did anyone figure out how to get the driver working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:**
I had the same problem, but there is a simple solution:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-mga
```

... restart X or reboot your system. I don't have a xorg.conf (autodetect) and the resolution is now the right one. Now I have to deal with a very laggy graphical response. I'll update my post, if I found a working solution.

EDIT 1:
I installed the new mga-driver v1.6.5. But I don't have any DRI support. Resizing/redrawing windows is still laggy.

**lshw -c video**

```
  *-display UNGEFORDERT   
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: G200eR2
       Hersteller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:07:00.0
       Version: 01
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       Konfiguration: latency=64 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16
       Ressourcen: memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:92800000-92803fff memory:92000000-927fffff
```

**Xorg.0.log**
http://pastebin.com/fjuvrXwg

Comment: This should be installed by default.

Comment: Running sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-mga did help, it gave me a resolution of 1024 x 768, which is gar better than the 640 x 480 it was at, but it has not completely resolved my problem.

If anyone has any suggestions on what I need to do in order to get my full resolution range for my Dell IN2030 monitor, I would appreciate the suggestions.  I run it at 1600 x 900 on my desktop. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have a `xorg.conf`? If so, rename/ move it and test your system without this config file. If the config file could not be found during X11-startup, the system will create a temporary new one based on your system hardware. I don't have a `xorg.conf` on my server.

Comment: I do not have xorg.conf

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue. Major lag, but a decent resolution.