# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS GUI is unusably slow with Matrox G200eR2 (Dell r720xd server)

Tags: 18.04, xorg, dell

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS GUI is unusably slow with Matrox G200eR2 (Dell r720xd server).

The gui during install was working smoothly. Also if I boot into safe graphics mode ( https://askubuntu.com/a/901327/299013 ) the GUI just works.

However booting normally the login screen is unusably slow. I get maybe 1 frame every 5 seconds. Then as soon as I log in I get a corrupt picture. Every line in the picture is successively shifted to the right. I can't decipher what is shown.

If I try to run `sudo X -configure` I get

> .Org X Server 1.19.6
>   Release Date: 2017-12-20
>   X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
>   Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
>   Current Operating System: Linux markus-PowerVault-DL2300
>   4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64                                                                                                                   Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
>   root=UUID=6c37f246-2ca0-4c5d-94c6-ae2a320a0c11 ro quiet splash
>   vt.handoff=1
>   Build Date: 13 April 2018  08:07:36PM
>   xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4 (For technical support please see
>   http://www.ubuntu.com/support)                          Current
>   version of pixman: 0.34.0
>   Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
>   to make sure that you have the latest version.
>   Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
>   (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
>   (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
>   (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jul 28 23:25:09 2018
>   (EE)
>   (EE) Backtrace:
>   (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x558b05e108ad]
>   (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x558b05c58000+0x1bc649) [0x558b05e14649] 
>   (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f1e2d349000+0x12890)
>   [0x7f1e2d35b890]                                 (EE) 3:
>   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x558b05c58000+0xb2294) [0x558b05d0a294]
>   (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xf86BusProbe+0x9) [0x558b05ce2229]
>   (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0x7f1) [0x558b05cf0e51]
>   (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x558b05c58000+0x56cd3) [0x558b05caecd3]
>   (EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xe7)
>   [0x7f1e2cf79b97]                                       (EE) 8:
>   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x558b05c98b8a]
>   (EE)
>   (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x50
>   (EE)
>   Fatal server error:
>   (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
>   (EE)
>   (EE)
>   Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
>   at http://wiki.x.org
>   for help.
>   (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for
>   additional information.                                (EE)
>   (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
>   Aborted

Next I tried to install `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-mga` ( https://askubuntu.com/a/875698/299013 ) but that doesn't exist.

Next I tried to remove all `apt remove xserver-xorg-video-\*` packages and only `apt install xserver-xorg-video-vesa`. (https://www.systutorials.com/241655/ubuntus-gui-response-is-very-slow/) But that didn't seem to make any difference.

What can I do to fix the graphics output?

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/8x0pal/need_some_help_installing_mga_driver_in_ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Everything "works" if you uncomment
`WaylandEnable=false`
in
`/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.

Source: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

I still however get some server-xorg-core crashes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to putting `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` as user643011 said, I was able to make it work by installing Debian 9 package:

```
wget ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-video-mga/xserver-xorg-video-mga_1.6.5-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-video-mga_1.6.5-1_amd64.deb
```

and adding `blacklist mgag200` to the blacklisted kernel modules in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` then running `update-initramfs -u`